# Flutter FireStore empty list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm trying to read the ID of each doc in a collection. As I can saw, doc.id is a string, and it has the value name for each doc. So I just tried to add that value to a list, for later pass it to a DropDownButton. But for some reason, the list return null.

```
  List<String> readthishit() {
    List<String> ex;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Enrollment')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
                ex.add(doc.id);
              })
            });
    return ex;
  }
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `await` keyword & wait for the result from `Firebase`.

Currently, you are sending a call to the `Firebase` but, before the result from `Firebase`, your code is returning the `null` list `ex`.

```
    Future<List<String>> readThisShit() async {
      List<String> ex = <String>[];
      final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Enrollment')
          .get();


      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
          ex.add(doc.id);
      });

      return ex;
  }
```

Also, I think you should use `lowerCamelCase` notation for your method names. So, `readthisshit` will become `readThisShit`.

Comment: I also tried the `async` keyword in the function but I never would have thought that I needed the `await` keyword in the `FirebaseFirestore.instance`. Now it works perfectly. Thanks!  (I need to wait 4min to accept your answer, as soon as I can I'll accept it.)

Comment: Thanks, buddy. Happy to help.